# How to create all django apps inside a folder?

Tags: python, django

Here is my project folder structure:

```
.venv [virtual environment]
apps
budgetApp
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
manage.py
```

When I run the following command `python manage.py startapp budget` it creates a new folder named budget beside the folder budgetApp.

But I want to create all my apps folder inside the `apps` folder.

Comment: move the folder after it was created into the apps folder. Then don't forget to change the path to the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Actually, I want to create the app from the command line, don't want to do it manually.

Comment: I'm just saying, after you create it on the command-line, you can move it to where you want it (or create it directly in the right place by specifying the path).

Comment: well, but I don't want to do it manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. At first, you need to create a directory `Your_App_Name` inside the `/apps` folder.
2. After that, run the following command to create the new app

```
python manage.py startapp Your_App_Name ./apps/Your_Apps_Folder_Name/
```

Then don't forget to add just created app name in the `settings.py` like below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'apps.Your_App_Name',
]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can specify the path to destination directory after *app_label* in the `startapp` command.

`python manage.py startapp <app_label> [destination]`

In your case you the command is like this:

`python manage.py startapp budget ./apps`

Then you should add just created app name in *settings.py* like below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'apps.budget',
]
```

Comment: I want different apps inside the `apps` folder. For example product app, sale app, customer app. That's why I need different folders inside the apps folder. The problem is not about a single app.

Comment: @KishorSterling So you need to do it on each app creation!

Comment: @KishorSterling My answer works exactly like the selected answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it like this

```
cd apps && django-admin startapp app_name
```

Answer (score 2):

First run `python manage.py startapp budget app/budget`

Then, on your `settings.py`, change the `INSTALLED_APPS` to the full path name:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'app.budget.apps.BudgetConfig',
]
```

Comment: Oops!! I got the following error!
`Destination directory 'D:\python\djangoprojects\budgetApp\apps\foo' does not exist, please create it first.`
This is okay, I've to create the apps directory first.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, you'll first need to create a folder `app/budget`. Then add the file `__init__.py` to the folder `add`. Then run the command `py manage.py startapp budget app/budget`.
Then, on your `settings.py`, change the INSTALLED_APPS to the full path

```
name:`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'app.budget',
]`
```

also need to change the name of the app in `apps.py` as follows

```
class BudgetConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'app.budget'
```

Comment: this is the true solution for the question

Answer (score 0):

When you use a nested structure for apps, you also need to change the name of the app in `apps.py` as follows:

```py
class BudgetConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.budget'
```

Check https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24801 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am making the following assumptions:

> 1. You are on a Unix/Linux PC
> 2. Your app is named: **perstep**

```bash
1. mkdir -p apps/perstep && touch apps/__init__.py
2. python manage.py startapp perstep ./apps/perstep

OR

1. mkdir -p apps && touch apps/__init__.py
2. cd apps && django-admin startapp perstep
```

## configurations

> reference the added diagram when in doubt.

```
1. In settings.py "INSTALLED_APPS" add "apps.perstep.apps.PerstepConfig" to it.

├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── perstep
│       ├── apps.py

2. Change name = 'apps.perstep' within 'apps > perstep > apps.py' PerstepConfig
```

This works as at **Django==4.0.5**